# Swift 4, Xcode 9: Getting and displaying the user's location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to get and display the user's location, but the simulator will only load the country I am in. I set up the required info.plist sections (privacy - location when in use and always), linked the mapView in Main.storyoard to the delegate (control-dragged to View Controller Icon), attached the IBOutlet (checked it to make sure it is properly connected) and wrote this code in viewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        let location = locations[0]
        let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I am just getting my feet wet with MapKit and this issue has been keeping me back for quite some time. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please use iPhone Device to get current location. In simulator, you have to set location then get that loaction. So can do this easily using device. You code will work with real device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I didn't realize the simulator wouldn't do it. That should work now.

Comment: You can use Simulator to show user location as long as you know who the user is.  It won't be you.  Hint: a red fruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use iPhone Device to get the current location. In the simulator, you have to set location then get that location. So can do this easily using the device. Your code will work with the real device.

If you want to test it with simulator the follow https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/location-simulation-in-xcode-ff7db9042710